# Search for value in radGridView using C# just finds values in first row of radGridView

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm trying to search for a value in a `radGridView` in C#. I found many solutions about that but for some reason it just searches in the first row of my `GridView`. You can see my code here:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in the textbox!");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        gridViewContact.SelectionMode = GridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in gridViewContact.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text) || row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text) || row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                row.IsSelected = true;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing found!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I search for a value, it always shows me the message box "Nothing found...". Except when I search for a value which is in the first row. So it just finds the values in the first row and nowhere else.

Any suggestions?

PS: I'm using Telerik controls

**EDIT:** Here you can see the gridView:

[image]

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you sure that you have values that match your search term? Consider whitespaces, etc... It would be good to see particular example(row values and search term) in your qestion...

Comment: I edited my question so you can see the gridView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `MessageBox` is misplaced. Try this:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in the textbox!");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        gridViewContact.SelectionMode = GridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        bool found = false;
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in gridViewContact.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text) || row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text) || row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                found = true;
                row.IsSelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this works, but case sensitive. how to disable that? The property "CaseSensitive" is already on false in my gridView

Comment: `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper())`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Telerik Grid View, I would suggest using Telerik search row instead of adding custom search row. For me it works like a charm.

```
this.radGridView1.AllowSearchRow = true;
```

[image: Here is the screenshot showing how the search works.]